# Toshiba Laptop C855-S5306

Tags: windows, windows-8, vpn, windows-8.1, juniper

I recently upgrade my laptop to windows 8.1 and now I can't run the Juniper terminal to connect to the company VPN. At the moment to click on the virtual machine it launches the terminal and after a few seconds a messages popup appears saying: juniper terminal services client has stopped working When I had windows 8, I was able to run Juniper without any problem. But in Windows 8.1 seems there are compatibilities issues.

"The response/answer to this question was that Juniper Supports knows about the issues and will release a fix later this year"

How does that help now?  I need to log into my work VPN almost on a daily basis, and with the weather issues in Iowa, some days I'm not able to make it into the office because I live out of town from my work office, so having my work VPN is crucial.

Any other answers for this question?  Will call the Juniper Support help?  Is their another upgrade to Windows 8.1 that will fix the problem and logging into my work VPN will not be an issues?  Please much help is needed ASAP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juniper is [currently not Windows 8.1 compatible](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB28018).

**When will Juniper Network's SSL VPN platforms and UAC platforms support Windows 8.1 (codenamed Windows Blue) Internet Explorer 11 (IE11) as a supported client to connect to SA and MAG SSL VPN platforms?**

> Juniper Networks is in the final stages of qualification process and
>   releasing software that supports Windows 8.1 and IE11 (schedule as
>   listed below) In the interim if you are experiencing an issue with the
>   features that are going to be supported and if the issue is not listed
>   below then please report it to Juniper by opening a support case